# gitlab-ci.yml variable with forward slashes

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

In some existing code I see the following syntax for variables in .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME////-}
```

What do the forward slashes with the hyphen mean?

Comment: If you're looking at this in a `script:` (or similar) section of your CI configuration, it's really a bash feature, not necessarily a GitLab feature, and only works on runners using shells (such as bash) that support this. Windows powershell executors, for example, wouldn't be able to use this syntax.

Comment: @sytech I didn't know what this syntax meant in the first place. Googling didn't help. Now that I know what it means, you are right that it is a `bash` feature and is applicable only in Linux runners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax pertains to regex substitution.

In the example it is assumed that `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` can have forward slashes and this would lead to some error if used with some commands like for e.g. docker commands. To fix this, substitute the forward slashes with a hyphen `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME////-}`

Breakdown of the logic

```
// replace every
/ forward slash
/ with
- hyphen
```

Test in a bash prompt

```
$ export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=abc/def/ghi
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
abc/def/ghi
$ echo ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME////-}
abc-def-ghi
```